# SQL query to retrieve the latest status of a process

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to track the status of multiple proposals that will be in either a "draft," "submitted," or "approved" status.  The proposals can go back and forth between draft and submitted multiple times before it is approved so, a junction table was created to track the proposal status changes by proposalPackageID, approvalTypeID, and reviewDate.  The query simply (ok, not so simply) needs to return a count of the various statuses.

I've gotten close with the following query (thanks to various posts on this site and google -- nothing really hits the nail on the head) but I'm missing some piece that is creating false counts.

```
SELECT        COUNT(distinctified.approvalTypeID) AS MyCount, distinctified.approvalTypeID, refProposalApprovalType.approvalDescription
FROM            (SELECT r.proposalPackageID, r.approvalTypeID, MAX(reviewedDate) AS MRD
                          FROM  proposalReviewAction as r INNER JOIN proposalPackage ON r.proposalPackageID = proposalPackage.proposalPackageID
                          WHERE proposalPackage.proposalCallID = 7   --  7=MAIN  8=Sat
                          GROUP BY r.approvalTypeID, r.proposalPackageID) as distinctified INNER JOIN proposalPackage ON distinctified.proposalPackageID = proposalPackage.proposalPackageID
                          INNER JOIN refProposalApprovalType ON distinctified.approvalTypeID = refProposalApprovalType.approvalTypeID
                          WHERE (proposalPackage.proposalCallID = 7)   --  7=MAIN  8=Sat
group by distinctified.approvalTypeID, refProposalApprovalType.approvalDescription
HAVING   (distinctified.approvalTypeID = 25) or (distinctified.approvalTypeID = 50) --25 = submitted 50 = approved
order by approvalTypeID
```

SORRY, had to step away and I forgot to paste the schema and the data...

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[proposalPackage](
    [proposalPackageID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [title] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [proposalCallID][int] NULL,
    [startDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [endDate] [datetime] NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [dbo].[proposalPackage]
           ([title]
           ,[proposalCallID]
           ,[startDate]
           ,[endDate])
     VALUES
       ('test proposal 1',7,'2018-10-01','2019-09-30')
       ,('test proposal 2',7,'2018-10-01','2019-09-30')
       ,('test proposal 3',7,'2018-10-01','2019-09-30')
       ,('test proposal 4',7,'2018-10-01','2019-09-30')
       ,('test proposal 5',7,'2018-10-01','2019-09-30')
       ,('test proposal 6',7,'2018-10-01','2019-09-30')
       ,('test proposal 7',7,'2018-10-01','2019-09-30')
       ,('test proposal 8',7,'2018-10-01','2019-09-30')
       ,('test proposal 9',7,'2018-10-01','2019-09-30')
       ,('test proposal 10',7,'2018-10-01','2019-09-30')


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[refProposalApprovalType](
    [approvalTypeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [approvalDescription] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [dbo].[refProposalApprovalType]
           ([approvalTypeID]
           ,[approvalDescription])
     VALUES
            (5,'Rejected by Approving Official')
            ,(10,'Rejected by PM')
            ,(15,'Rejected by Executive Review Board')
            ,(25,'Submitted for Approval')
            ,(50,'Approved by Approving Official')
            ,(75,'Approved by PM')
            ,(100,'Approved by Executive Review Board')

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[proposalReviewAction](
    [proposalReviewActionID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [proposalPackageID] [int] NULL,
    [approvalTypeID] [int] NULL,
    [comments] [varchar](2000) NULL,
    [reviewedByID] [int] NULL,
    [reviewedDate] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [dbo].[proposalReviewAction]
           ([proposalPackageID]
           ,[approvalTypeID]
           ,[comments]
           ,[reviewedByID]
           ,[reviewedDate])
     VALUES
           (1,25,'Submit',101,'2018-05-01')
           ,(2,25,'Submit',102,'2018-05-01')
           ,(3,25,'Submit',103,'2018-05-01')
           ,(4,25,'Submit',104,'2018-05-01')
           ,(5,25,'Submit',105,'2018-05-01')
           ,(1,10,'Incomplete',1001,'2018-05-10')
           ,(2,10,'Incomplete',1001,'2018-05-10')
           ,(3,10,'Incomplete',1001,'2018-05-10')
           ,(4,50,'Approved',1001,'2018-05-10')
           ,(1,25,'Resubmit',101,'2018-05-21')
           ,(2,25,'Resubmit',102,'2018-05-21')
           ,(3,25,'Resubmit',103,'2018-05-21')
           ,(7,25,'Submit',107,'2018-05-22')
           ,(1,10,'REJECTED',1001,'2018-05-22')
           ,(2,10,'REJECTED',1001,'2018-05-22')
           ,(3,10,'Approved',1001,'2018-05-22')
           ,(1,25,'Resubmit',101,'2018-05-23')
           ,(8,25,'Submit',108,'2018-05-23')
           ,(10,25,'Submit',110,'2018-05-24')
           ,(3,15,'REJECTED',1010,'2018-05-25')
```

I would expect to see

```
MyCount   approvalTypeID  approvalDescription
  6          25           Submitted for Review
  1          50           Approved by Approving Official
```

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: DDL and sample data would help this question tremendously.

Comment: We don't know your schema. Please provide the tables' structure (as `CREATE TABLE` statements). Also we don't know your data, so please also provide sample data (as `INSERT INTO` statements). And to make it easier for us to understand what you want an where the problem is, please also include the actual result you get with the provided sample data, state where this result is wrong and include an expected result that should be produced with the sample data provided.

Comment: Don't just dump broken query and expect to understand what you are trying to do!!!  Where's your table structure???  Sample input???  Expected output???  Learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Additional information added...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your subquery was not correctly getting the latest status for each package.

If possible using the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function makes it easy to identify the latest status row for each package while keeping the other column values for that row.

The following query would get you just the latest status for each package:

```
SELECT ls.* 
  FROM (
    SELECT r.proposalPackageID,
           r.approvalTypeID,
           RowNr = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY r.proposalPackageID ORDER BY r.reviewedDate DESC) 
      FROM proposalReviewAction AS r
      JOIN proposalPackage AS pp ON pp.proposalPackageID = r.proposalPackageID
      WHERE pp.proposalCallID = 7) AS ls  --  7=MAIN  8=Sat
  WHERE ls.RowNr = 1
    AND ls.approvalTypeID IN (25, 50); -- 25 = sumbitted 50 = approved
```

Note the `WHERE ls.RowNr = 1` which is the filter removing older statuses. Ensure that the filter for `approvalTypeID IN (25, 50)` is on the outside of the subquery so that we get the true latest status for each package.

Then it is a simple task to join to other tables to return additional columns from those tables to match whatever output format you prefer.

Comment: thanks, works perfect now.
What does the # mean in front of the table names?

Comment: #=Temporary table, which I used to check the answer. I shall clean it up.

Comment: so the solution you provided works like a charm, thanks again. However, management now wants some additional details (of course they do, right?).  I've put the query into an "EXISTS" statement and added some joins and get what looks like a good set of data.  The problem is, when I run the query above, it returns a list of 95 proposals.  Since that query is now in an "EXISTS" statement, i would expect it to return 95 or fewer proposals.  I'm getting 112...
I don't have enough space here to insert the new query, How do I do that?

Comment: Could you post a separate question, it is a little hard to get the full picture from your comment?

Comment: I did... sorry for the confusion...<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51046748/follow-up-to-sql-query-to-retrieve-the-latest-status-of-a-process?noredirect=1#comment89085575_51046748>

and, I figured it out...