# FOLLOW UP to SQL query to retrieve the latest status of a process

Tags: sql-server

The original question and schema are shown at the following link:
[SQL query to retrieve the latest status of a process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50633735/sql-query-to-retrieve-the-latest-status-of-a-process/50635490?noredirect=1#comment88441527_50635490)

The solution provided by @mendosi was perfect.  However, now that the deadline for submission is past, management wants more information.  I've been able to give them the information they want using the following query (incorporating the aforementioned solution into the "EXISTS" clause):

```
SELECT        
    proposalPackage.proposalPackageID, refProposalType.name, proposalPackage.title, 
    [user].lastName, [user].firstName, [user].email, [user].phone, 
    proposalReviewAction.approvalTypeID
FROM
    proposalReviewAction, proposalPackage 
INNER JOIN
    refProposalType ON proposalPackage.proposalTypeID = refProposalType.proposalTypeID 
INNER JOIN
    proposalManagerAssignment ON proposalPackage.proposalPackageID = proposalManagerAssignment.proposalPackageID 
INNER JOIN
    [user] ON proposalManagerAssignment.userID = [user].userID
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT ls.* 
            FROM 
                (SELECT 
                     r.proposalPackageID, r.approvalTypeID,
                     RowNr = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY r.proposalPackageID ORDER BY r.reviewedDate DESC) 
                 FROM 
                     proposalReviewAction AS r
                 JOIN 
                     proposalPackage AS pp ON pp.proposalPackageID = r.proposalPackageID
                 WHERE 
                     pp.proposalCallID = 7) AS ls
            WHERE 
                ls.RowNr = 1
                AND (ls.approvalTypeID = 50))
GROUP BY 
    proposalPackage.proposalTypeID, [user].lastName, [user].firstName,
    [user].email, [user].phone, proposalPackage.title, 
    refProposalType.name, proposalManagerAssignment.isPrimary, 
    proposalPackage.proposalCallID, approvalTypeID, 
    proposalPackage.proposalPackageID, proposalReviewAction.approvalTypeID
HAVING        
    (proposalManagerAssignment.isPrimary = 1) 
    AND (proposalPackage.proposalCallID = 7) 
    AND (approvalTypeID = 50)
ORDER BY  
    proposalPackage.proposalPackageID
```

My problem seems to be that the subquery in the Exists clause returns 95 rows (as it should) limiting the results to those with a status of 50.

As I understand the EXISTS clause, the results should be limited to those records that "exist" in the subquery that follows... right?  So, in this case, if a record does not exist in the subquery, it will not exist in the final result...??

The problem is, I'm getting 112 records when there are only 95 records to choose from (or join on) in the results list of the subquery.

So, I try to limit is by adding some additional qualifiers and joins to the subquery:

```
SELECT        
    proposalPackage.proposalPackageID, refProposalType.name, 
    proposalPackage.title, 
    [user].lastName, [user].firstName, [user].email, [user].phone, 
    proposalReviewAction.approvalTypeID
FROM            
    proposalReviewAction, proposalPackage 
INNER JOIN
    refProposalType ON proposalPackage.proposalTypeID = refProposalType.proposalTypeID 
INNER JOIN
    proposalManagerAssignment ON proposalPackage.proposalPackageID = proposalManagerAssignment.proposalPackageID 
INNER JOIN
    [user] ON proposalManagerAssignment.userID = [user].userID
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT ls.* 
            FROM 
                (SELECT 
                     r.proposalPackageID,
                     r.approvalTypeID,
                     RowNr = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY r.proposalPackageID ORDER BY r.reviewedDate DESC) 
                 FROM
                     proposalReviewAction AS r
                 JOIN 
                     proposalPackage AS pp ON pp.proposalPackageID = r.proposalPackageID
                 WHERE 
                     pp.proposalCallID = 7) AS ls 
            WHERE 
                ls.RowNr = 1
                AND (ls.approvalTypeID = 50)) AS distinctified
INNER JOIN 
    proposalPackage ON distinctified.proposalPackageID = proposalPackage.proposalPackageID
INNER JOIN 
    refProposalApprovalType ON distinctified.approvalTypeID = refProposalApprovalType.approvalTypeID
GROUP BY 
    proposalPackage.proposalTypeID, [user].lastName, [user].firstName, 
    [user].email, [user].phone, proposalPackage.title, refProposalType.name, 
    proposalManagerAssignment.isPrimary, proposalPackage.proposalCallID, 
    approvalTypeID, proposalPackage.proposalPackageID, proposalReviewAction.approvalTypeID
HAVING        
    (proposalManagerAssignment.isPrimary = 1) 
    AND (proposalPackage.proposalCallID = 7) 
    AND (distinctified.approvalTypeID = 50)
ORDER BY  
    proposalPackage.proposalPackageID
```

Now, when I add the "AS distinctified" statement with a couple of JOINS to the subquery, I get a "SYNTAX ERROR near AS" error.  I also get an "Expecting ( or SELECT" at each of the "HAVING" qualifiers.

I don't think I'm making this too complicated but that remains a possibility.  It seems to me it is a matter (at this point) of overlooking a character somewhere.

Thanks in advance for the assist... AGAIN!!

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a forum. Questions are self-contained and separate from one another. If you need to reference a previous question, then you're doing it wrong. Please read [ask] and go through the [faq].

Comment: Learn how to use table alias.  Repeating long table names on each line is very annoying.  Also learn to format your code.  No one is going to read that pile of code.

Comment: That's not how `EXISTS` works, it works by looking in your sub-query to see if anything exists.  Well guess what, it does, 95 rows of data exist there.  So it returns *every* row for you.  The solution is to reference your outer query in your `EXISTS` clause, but to do this you should really introduce some aliases.  I would suggest writing a much simpler query to check out how this all hangs together before going back to your much larger/ complex query?

Comment: Slight detour....you really need to start using ANSI-92 style joins instead of a comma separated list of tables. They have been available for more than 25 years now. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: This code is a trainwreck. You have joins AFTER the where clause. You are trying to add an alias to EXISTS predicate in your where clause. And your EXISTS needs to be a correlated subquery. As it sits right now that query has no relevance to the main query. If you took the time to format your code legibly it becomes very clear how many issues you have going on here.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer to your much more complex example, but it should explain what the root cause is hopefully?

```
DECLARE @x TABLE (id INT);
INSERT INTO @x SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3;
DECLARE @y TABLE (id INT);
INSERT INTO @y SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 3;

--This is what you are doing
SELECT * FROM @x WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @y);

--This is what you should be doing
SELECT * FROM @x x WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @y y WHERE y.id = x.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I really have no idea what you are trying to accomplish but here is what your query might look like with some aliases and formatting. I also moved the joins before the where clause and removed the alias on your EXISTS predicate. But you are referencing distinctified in the code which I just don't get. As such there are some issues in this query still but without an understanding of what the need is I don't know what to do to help.

```
SELECT pp.proposalPackageID
    , pt.name
    , pp.title
    , u.lastName
    , u.firstName
    , u.email
    , u.phone
    , pra.approvalTypeID
FROM proposalReviewAction pra 
--,  proposalPackage pp --why is this table here? It is joined to again later
INNER JOIN refProposalType pt ON pp.proposalTypeID = pt.proposalTypeID 
INNER JOIN proposalManagerAssignment ma ON pp.proposalPackageID = ma.proposalPackageID 
INNER JOIN [user] u ON ma.userID = u.userID
INNER JOIN proposalPackage pp ON distinctified.proposalPackageID = pp.proposalPackageID
INNER JOIN refProposalApprovalType pat ON distinctified.approvalTypeID = pat.approvalTypeID
WHERE EXISTS 
(
    SELECT ls.* 
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT r.proposalPackageID,
            r.approvalTypeID,
            RowNr = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY r.proposalPackageID ORDER BY r.reviewedDate DESC) 
        FROM proposalReviewAction AS r
        JOIN proposalPackage AS pp2 ON pp2.proposalPackageID = r.proposalPackageID
        WHERE pp2.proposalCallID = 7
    ) AS ls 
    WHERE ls.RowNr = 1
        AND ls.approvalTypeID = 50
)                 
GROUP BY pp.proposalTypeID
    , u.lastName
    , u.firstName
    , u.email
    , u.phone
    , pp.title
    , pt.name
    , ma.isPrimary
    , pp.proposalCallID
    , approvalTypeID
    , pp.proposalPackageID
    , pra.approvalTypeID
HAVING ma.isPrimary = 1
    AND pp.proposalCallID = 7
    AND distinctified.approvalTypeID = 50
ORDER BY pp.proposalPackageID
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured it out... once I realized I had the wrong understanding of EXISTS (thanks @Richard Hansel).  Final query: (properly formatted and aliased)

```
SELECT        pp.proposalPackageID
            , r_pt.name
            , pp.title
            , u.lastName
            , u.firstName
            , u.email
            , u.phone
            , pra.approvalTypeID
FROM          proposalReviewAction AS pra
            , proposalPackage AS pp
            INNER JOIN refProposalType AS r_pt ON pp.proposalTypeID = r_pt.proposalTypeID 
            INNER JOIN proposalManagerAssignment AS pma ON pp.proposalPackageID = pma.proposalPackageID 
            INNER JOIN [user] AS u ON pma.userID = u.userID
WHERE       EXISTS 
            (SELECT ls.* 
             FROM 
                     (SELECT r.proposalPackageID,
                             r.approvalTypeID,
                             RowNr = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY r.proposalPackageID ORDER BY r.reviewedDate DESC) 
                      FROM   proposalReviewAction AS r
                             JOIN proposalPackage AS pp ON pp.proposalPackageID = r.proposalPackageID
                      WHERE  pp.proposalCallID = 7) AS ls 
              WHERE ls.RowNr = 1
                    AND (ls.approvalTypeID = 50)
                    AND (pra.proposalPackageID = pp.proposalPackageID))
GROUP BY pp.proposalTypeID
        , u.lastName
        , u.firstName
        , u.email
        , u.phone
        , pp.title
        , r_pt.name
        , pma.isPrimary
        , pp.proposalCallID
        , approvalTypeID
        , pp.proposalPackageID
        , pra.approvalTypeID
HAVING  (pma.isPrimary = 1) 
        AND (pp.proposalCallID = 7) 
        AND (pra.approvalTypeID = 50)
ORDER BY  pp.proposalTypeID
```